# make_pair and push_back base pointers and instantiate a vector of base pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

My first problem is that I cannot instantiate a vector of pointers and the second problem is that the push_back does not work with make_pair. Can someone please help?

The error is

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<Base>::unique_ptr(Derived&)’
```

and

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<Base>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > >::push_back(std::pair<Base*, Base*>)’
```

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

void someFunction(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > & vec) {

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>::iterator it = vec.begin();

    std::vector<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<Base>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > > pairWise;
    pairWise.push_back(std::make_pair((*it).get(), (*it).get()));

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    Base a;
    std::vector<Derived> derivedObjects(2);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > vecPtr = {derivedObjects.begin(), derivedObjects.end()};
    someFunction(vecPtr);


}
```

Comment: [Don't `#include <bits/*>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2069064)!

Comment: @Barry ok, I have included <memory> instead.

Comment: Do you want copies in your pair ? you cannot move the same `unique_ptr` into the 2 parts of the pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code here:

```
std::vector<Derived> derivedObjects(2);
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > vecPtr = {derivedObjects.begin(), derivedObjects.end()};
```

Isn't quite correct. I suspect you wanted to use `std::vector`'s range based constructor to make a copy of all the `Derived` objects in `derivedObjects` into a new vector of `std::unique_ptr<Base>` - it wouldn't work, because there is no valid constructor for `std::unique_ptr<Base>` that takes `Derived`.

Secondly, your use of uniform brace initializer there isn't quite correct.

---

I suspect you want this:

```
std::vector<Derived> derivedObjects(2);
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vecPtr;
std::transform(derivedObjects.begin(), derivedObjects.end(), std::back_inserter(vecPtr),
    [](auto& p){ return std::make_unique<Base>(p); });
```

What this does is to

- take each `Derived` object in `derivedObjects` and calls our lambda object, which in-turn transforms that `Derived` object to a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and returns it.
- The returned "transformation" is then assigned to the iterator returned by `std::back_inserter` (and of cause incremented). `std::back_inserter` is more a less an "STL iterator style" of doing `std::vector<T, Alloc>::push_back(...)`

---

**UPDATE**

In regards to your comment:

```
void someFunction(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > & vec) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    std::vector<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<Base>, std::unique_ptr<Base> > > pairWise;
    pairWise.push_back(std::make_pair((*it).get(), (*it).get()));
}
```

It's unclear whether you want to push a copy of *std::pair* or `std::unique_ptr<Base>`s into `pairwise`, because `std::unique_ptr`s cannot be copied. ONly moved.

If you want to move: You can replace the last line with:

```
pairWise.emplace_back(std::move(*it), std::move(*it));
//You shouldn't rely on the UB above of moving twice from the same object
```

If it's a copy (a bit nasty because your design is quite not nice or unclear to me):

```
pairWise.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Base>(*(*it).get()), std::make_unique<Base>(*(*it).get()));
```

Comment: It works. I just had to change the compiler settings to c++14, since it did not work in c++11.  Can you please address the second problem with make_pair?

Comment: I did want to make a pair of identical pointers ( pointing to the derived class )  and put them into the variable pairWise. But I have to read your answer thorougly first. Also, if the base class is abstract, then the code with std::transform doesnt work.

Comment: @infoclogged, you cannot have a `std::unique_ptr` of an abstract base class. In fact, if `Base` was abstract, then your code snippet would never have worked, even from the declaration, `Base a` - Cannot work

Comment: Yes, I got it.. The working copy is much more complicated than the example I posted here. But I have got the whole point. The use of unique_ptr is absolutely not required here. Thanks for your time.